# Showing loading message on table row in angular2

Tags: css, angular

```
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let item of  _studentList let i=index">
    <td  align='center'>{{ i }}--{{item.rollno}}</td>
    <td  align='center'>{{item.sname}}</td>
    <td  align='center'>{{item.status!='NOT'?item.status:''}}</td>
    <td  align='center'>
        <input type='checkbox'   style='height:15px; width:15px;' [checked]="item.status=='P'"  (change)="onChangePA(item)"  ></td>
  <td  align='center'>
   <a><img src='../images/d.jpg' height='30' width='30' /> </a>
 </td>
 </tr>
 </tbody>
```

[image]

When ever i change the checkbox I will do API request, until i get the response I want to either `disable that row` or `showing loading on row`

how to do it?

I want  only one loading not all. how to do it?

[image]

Comment: are you making an api call after click on checkbox?

Comment: yes I am updating data in database so it take some time so i want to show waiting msg on row so not allow click again on same row before completing first process

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make table row as component and disable input as below
import {Component, Input} from '@angular/core'

```
@Component({
  selector: 'table-body',
  template: `

    <td  align='center'>{{ i }}--{{item.rollno}}</td>
    <td  align='center'>{{item.sname}}</td>
    <td  align='center'>{{item.status!='NOT'?item.status:''}}</td>
    <td  align='center'>
        <input type='checkbox' style='height:15px; width:15px;' [checked]="item.status=='P'"  (change)="onChangePA(item)" [disabled]="disableinput"></td>
  <td  align='center'>
   <a><img src='../images/d.jpg' height='30' width='30' /> </a>
 </td>
  `,
})
export class tBody {
  @Input() item:any;
   @Input() i:any;
  disableinput: false;
  onChangePA(val) {
    this.disablebody = true;
//do your stuff 
  }
}
```

Your main template will be as below

```
  <table>
  <thead>
  <tr>
  <th>Roll</th>
  <th></th>
  <th>Status</th>
  <th>Action</th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let item of  _studentList let i=index">
      <table-body [item]="item" [i]="i"></table-body>
 </tr>
 </tbody>
 </table>
```

[Plunk Link](http://plnkr.co/edit/4OqxOKIbjh6Zs8bZj0F8?p=preview)

Comment: Updated plunkr please check now.

Comment: still not working for mutiple row and your plunkr not showing any output

Comment: check properly i am able to see plunkr output.

Comment: ReferenceError: System is not defined  console showing this error

Answer (score 2):

[Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/3C8fiX9H9OA5l44oAYkl?p=preview)

Basically you will need to have a variable in the component which informs the template whether the api call is initiated or completed.

Initially "showLoading" will be false. Set it to "true" when the api call is being made. After you get the response set it to "false".

And in your template, you will have a **"class binding"** like this -

```
<div>
      <div [class.loading]=showLoading>
        I'm a div that wants to be styled
      </div>
      <button (click)="toggle()">Toggle</button>
</div>

class App {
  public showLoading = false;

  toggle() {
    this.showLoading = !this.showLoading;
  } 
}
```

Comment: sorry did not get you?

Comment: I want to pass different loading for row then above not work for me

Comment: what different loading? be specific

Comment: suppose when I click on first rollno checkbox then for only that row showing  loading msg  same for other it easy to clearify which row updating

Comment: please put your code in some online editor and I will help you out.

Comment: when I used single id it call all loading image check in question I want here only single which I clicked  row checbox

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try this

In Html:

```
<input type="checkbox" (change)="onClick()" [disabled]="isDisable" />
```

In .ts file:

```
export class YourComponent {

  isDisable = false;

  onClick() {
    this.isDisable = true;
    //Your code here
    this.isDisable = false;
  }
```